# FILTRO DE BÚSQUEDA EN PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy haciendo un sitio para mostrar menús de diferentes comercios, tengo un código para un buscador,en este caso de menús de comidas,debe filtrar por ciudad sin embargo si pongo un menu que no corresponde a la cuidad especificada siempre lo muestra,a la hora de mostrar los resultados sin buscar nada sí que funciona pero a la hora de filtrar es dónde está el problema,en la consola del phpmyadmin también me muestra los resultados que no debería, este es el código:

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    // Include pagination library file
    
  
  // Set some useful configuration
  $baseURL = 'getMenu.php';
  $offset = !empty($_POST['page'])?$_POST['page']:0;
  $limit = 5;
  
  
  // Set conditions for search
    $whereSQL = 'WHERE ciudad = "'.$_POST['ciudad'].'" ';
    if(!empty($_POST['keywords'])){
        var_dump($_POST['keywords']);
        $whereSQL = $whereSQL." AND  empresa LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' OR descripcion LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' ";
        var_dump($whereSQL);
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['precio_inicial'])) 
    {

   $whereSQL = $whereSQL." AND precio >= '".$_POST['precio_inicial']."' ";
   }

if (!empty($_POST['precio_final'])) {

$whereSQL = $whereSQL." AND precio <= '".$_POST['precio_final']."' ";
}

  
    /*if(isset($_POST['fecha1']) AND $_POST['fecha1'] != "" AND isset($_POST['fecha2']) AND $_POST['fecha2'] != ""){
        #$whereSQL .= (strpos($whereSQL, 'WHERE') !== false)?" AND ":" WHERE ";
        $whereSQL .= " AND fecha BETWEEN '".$fecha1."' AND '".$fecha2."' ";
    }*/

    
    
    // Include database configuration file
    include("dbConfig.php");
    include("Pagination.class.php");
  // Count of all records
    $query   = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as rowNum FROM menu ".$whereSQL);
    $result  = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $rowCount= $result['rowNum'];
  
  // Initialize pagination class
    $pagConfig = array(
        'baseURL' => $baseURL,
        'totalRows' => $rowCount,
        'perPage' => $limit,
    'currentPage' => $offset,
    'contentDiv' => 'dataContainer',
    'link_func' => 'searchFilter'
    );
    $pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);

    // Fetch records based on the offset and limit
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM menu $whereSQL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit");
?>
    <!-- Data list container -->
    
    
        <?php
        if($query->num_rows > 0){?>
         <div class="row gy-5"> 
      <?php
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $offset++
        ?>
            

              <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 menu-item">
                <img src="assets/img/menu/<?= $row["img"]; ?>" class="img-fluid img-circle centrada" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;">
                <p><?= $row["descripcion"]; ?></p>
                <p><?= $row["empresa"]; ?></p>
                <p class="ingredients">
                  
                </p>
                <p class="price">
                  $ <?= $row["precio"]; ?><br>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info ordenar">Pedir</button>
                </p>
              </div><!-- Menu Item -->


            
            <?php
                    }
        
        }else{ ?>
            <h2>No hay Registros</h2>
        <?php }
        ?>
      </div>
      <?= $pagination->createLinks(); ?>

      <?php
}
?>
```

Cualquier ayuda la agradeceré mucho.

Comment: **es donde esta el problema...** sigo sin entender donde esta el problema ...

Comment: Si en PHPmyAdmin te muestra sin filtrar, entonces es ahí donde esta el problema. Primero has que funcione tu query en el DBM y luego la pasas a PHP. Yo tendría cuidado con las comillas también.

Comment: @OCHOA  de acuerdo gracias